# How to pass values between two components

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

In a VF page, I have two   i.e. *A* and *B*.In first component,there is a search box. Second component will display data type in first component search box. So How can I pass data between these two components?
This is first Component where is search Box.

```
<apex:component controller="SuggestionDemoController">
      <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="block">
            <h1>Article and Record Suggestions</h1>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:panelGroup >

                        </apex:panelGroup>
                        <apex:panelGroup >
                            <apex:inputHidden id="nbResult" value="{!nbResult}"  />
                            <apex:outputLabel for="searchText">Search Text</apex:outputLabel>
                            &nbsp;
                            <apex:inputText id="searchText" value="{!searchText}"  onblur="abc()"/>
                            <apex:actionFunction action="{!doSuggest}" name="searcharti"/>
                            <apex:commandButton id="suggestButton" value="Suggest"  rerender="block" action="{!doSuggest}"/>

                        </apex:panelGroup>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
           </apex:pageblock>
          </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

This is second Component which is showing results searched in first componemt.

```
<apex:component controller="SuggestionDemoController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
              <apex:pageBlockSection title="Results" id="results" columns="1" rendered="{!results.size>0}">

               <apex:dataList value="{!results}" var="w" type="1">
                    <br />
                    <apex:panelGroup rendered="{!objectType=='KnowledgeArticleVersion'}">
                   Title:<apex:outputLink value="{!urlfor('/'+w.SObject['Id'],null,['popup' = 'true'])}">{!w.SObject['Title']}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:panelGroup>

               <!--   <apex:panelGroup rendered="{!objectType!='KnowledgeArticleVersion'}">
                        Name: {!w.SObject['Name']}
                    </apex:panelGroup> -->

                    <hr />
                </apex:dataList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
           </apex:pageBlock>
          </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using two components when you are using the same controller? Why don't you just render the results in the same component. The only way for them to communicate would be back through whatever page is calling them.

Answer (score 0):

On your search action, return a pagereference with an appended query string like so: `return new PageReference('/apex/yourpagename?search='+varSearch');`

Then on your page load, check if a querystring with the name 'search' exists, if yes, display search results.